# Why do we fix an extension of valuation of $K$ to $\overline{K}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $K$ be a valuation field. Let $v$ be a valuation of $K$.　Let $K_v$ be completion of $K$ at $v$.
I often encounter an expression.

> **Fix** an extension of $v$ to $\overline{K}$, which **serves to fixes** an embedding
> $\overline{K}\subset \overline{K_v}$.

but  cannot understand meaning of this by two reasons.

$1$. Extension of $v$ to any algebraic extension is unique. Why do we have to 'fix' it ?

$2$. The map $\overline{K}\subset \overline{K_v}$ is given by $a \to (a,a,a,・・・)$ and this has nothing to do with $v$. Why 'fixing extension of $v$' serves to define this map ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say what is meant without the context (and the exact wording, there seems to be at least one typo in what you wrote), but perhaps what is meant is that we fix the algebraic closure (and then extend the valuation in the unique way). Also what do you mean by $\bar K_v$? The residue field? I don't see why $\bar K$ would embed into it. The two don't even necessarily have the same characteristic. What the extension of the valuation does give us is the embedding of $K_v$ into $\bar K_v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The extension is not unique unless $K$ is complete with respec to $v$. Take a global field $K$, with $v$ being the valuation for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, then for any algebraic extension $K\subset K'$, the extension of $v$ to $K'$ is not necessarily unique, as the ideal $\mathfrak m$ may split in $\mathcal O_{K'}$.
2. Since $K_v$ is complete, for any finite extension $K_v\subset K'$, there is indeed a unique extension of $v$ to $K'$, hence there is a unique extension of $v$ to $\overline{K_v}$. An embedding $\overline{K}\hookrightarrow\overline{K_v}$ obviously induces a valuation on $\overline{K}$. On the other hand, fix a valuation on $\overline{K}$. For any algebraic extension $K\subset K(\alpha)$, we have $K_v\subset K(\alpha)_v$, and since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, it's also algebraic over $K_{\alpha}$, therefore $K_v(\alpha)$ is finite dimensional over $K_v$, there is a unique extension of $v$ to $K_v(\alpha)$ that must match the one on $K(\alpha)_v$. That is, $K(\alpha)$ can be isometrically embeded into $\overline{K_v}$. By Zorn's lemma or whatever, $\overline{K}$ can be isometrically embeded into $\overline{K_v}$.

More details can be found in the 8th chapter of [Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html), or Theorem 8.1 (Chapter II, Section 8) of [Neukirch's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03983-0).

Comment: Regarding 1, completeness is sufficient but not in general necessary for the uniqueness in question. Of course you are right that for global fields, the extensions in fact fail to be unique.